# How to auto deploy google app engine flexible using Container Registry with Build Trigger

Tags: google-app-engine, github, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I'm using GitHub to keep my projects. Using PHP storm I m pushing my script to GitHub repo.

I m using Google App engine flexible environment application. Whenever I push to my GitHub repo.
The latest script will auto deploy to Google App Engine Flexible Environment PHP project.So, I Created Build Trigger in GCP Container Registry.

Here are My PHP sample projects with Docker file

**web/index.php**

```
<?php

Echo 'this is sample project';

?>
```

**App.yaml**

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
 document_root: web

manual_scaling:
 instances: 1

handlers:

- url: .*
 script: index.php
```

**Composer.json**

```
{
   "require": {
       "php": "7.1.*"
   }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Docker: Google App Engine

FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/php
```

Using Google Cloud Platform Container Registry Build trigger.Created a build trigger. I got the below logs

**Build Logger**

```
starting build "4d51b494-5f7d-48e5-a2a2-6d7d6a9318a9"

FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-id/r/github-test
* branch 5f9ac268123a3cfef5876034f2933eb83b34cd6d -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at 5f9ac26 v 1
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon 87.04kB

Step 1/1 : FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/php
latest: Pulling from google-appengine/php
Digest: sha256:578584d281828af48df03b85dcdcfd5792e8eb2916567497b56468b
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google-appengine/php:latest
[91m# Executing 3 build triggers...
[0mStep 1/1 : COPY . $APP_DIR
Step 1/1 : RUN chown -R www-data.www-data $APP_DIR
---> Running in c9d98191fa2b
Step 1/1 : RUN /build-scripts/composer.sh
---> Running in ec2b02e5f0d1
[91m+ DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION=7.1
+ '[' -f /app/composer.json ']'
[0m[91m+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ CMD='php /build-scripts/detect_php_version.php /app/composer.json'
[0m[91m++ su www-data -c 'php /build-scripts/detect_php_version.php /app/composer.json'
[0mPHP_VERSION: 7.1
[91m+ PHP_VERSION=7.1
+ echo 'PHP_VERSION: 7.1'
+ '[' 7.1 == exact ']'
+ '[' 7.1 '!=' 5.6 ']'
+ '[' 7.1 '!=' 7.0 ']'
+ '[' 7.1 '!=' 7.1 ']'
+ '[' 7.1 == 5.6 ']'
+ '[' 7.1 == 7.0 ']'
+ COMPOSER_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ unset COMPOSER_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN
+ rm -rf /app/vendor
[0m[91m+ php -d auto_prepend_file= /build-scripts/install_extensions.php /app/composer.json /opt/php/lib/conf.d/extensions.ini 7.1
[0m[91m+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ NOSCRIPT=--no-scripts
+ cd /app
+ su -m www-data -c 'php -d auto_prepend_file='\'''\'' /usr/local/bin/composer install --no-scripts --no-dev --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-progress'
[0m[91mLoading composer repositories with package information
[0m[91mUpdating dependencies
[0m[91mNothing to install or update
[0m[91mWriting lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
[0m ---> 1c5b266fe5ef
Removing intermediate container 473f7595359f
Removing intermediate container c9d98191fa2b
Removing intermediate container ec2b02e5f0d1
Successfully built 1c5b266fe5ef
Successfully tagged gcr.io/project-id/github-test:5f9ac268123a3cfef5876034f2933eb83b34cd6d
PUSH
Pushing gcr.io/project-id/github-test:5f9ac268123a3cfef5876034f2933eb83b34cd6d
The push refers to a repository [gcr.io/project-id/github-test]
09e0b63e8b63: Preparing
9ab9de3bae7c: Preparing
7ca730235cb1: Preparing
bca74f739283: Preparing
83430675961e: Preparing
c4b086b9d099: Preparing
acf227e1b2a5: Preparing
40de2f738e9e: Preparing
0ef981ddb200: Preparing
73acc0dfea4b: Preparing
825db9ad6441: Preparing
23088c61aa93: Preparing
122586f0e47f: Preparing
357a1f7d4b42: Preparing
d7fe08acdf1d: Preparing
cd1b43d6d268: Preparing
23b7338cf1fe: Preparing
9301d4a8f319: Preparing
2126b271c428: Preparing
c4b086b9d099: Waiting
acf227e1b2a5: Waiting
40de2f738e9e: Waiting
0ef981ddb200: Waiting
73acc0dfea4b: Waiting
825db9ad6441: Waiting
23088c61aa93: Waiting
122586f0e47f: Waiting
357a1f7d4b42: Waiting
d7fe08acdf1d: Waiting
cd1b43d6d268: Waiting
23b7338cf1fe: Waiting
9301d4a8f319: Waiting
2126b271c428: Waiting
83430675961e: Layer already exists
bca74f739283: Layer already exists
c4b086b9d099: Layer already exists
40de2f738e9e: Layer already exists
acf227e1b2a5: Layer already exists
0ef981ddb200: Layer already exists
73acc0dfea4b: Layer already exists
825db9ad6441: Layer already exists
122586f0e47f: Layer already exists
23088c61aa93: Layer already exists
357a1f7d4b42: Layer already exists
d7fe08acdf1d: Layer already exists
cd1b43d6d268: Layer already exists
23b7338cf1fe: Layer already exists
9301d4a8f319: Layer already exists
2126b271c428: Layer already exists
09e0b63e8b63: Pushed
7ca730235cb1: Pushed
9ab9de3bae7c: Pushed
5f9ac268123a3cfef5876034f2933eb83b34cd6d: digest: sha256:c604792b8b384e1186b55d11a1d04e8e06051e3f3083c25bd13668dcf size: 4285
DONE
```

I want to deploy container image to GAE FE, So, I changed my docker file like this

**Dockerfile**

```
 # Docker: Google App Engine
   FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/php
   gcloud app deploy -image-url=gcr.io/project-id/github-test
```

I got this issues

```
starting build "43508598-4542-4e1c-a9e7-d29343878202"

FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-id/r/github-test
* branch ea7511b88ad5c59736037c37685ea699b5c0 -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at ea7511b v 1
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon 87.04kB

Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 7: Unknown instruction: GCLOUD
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:59e98ecdfe9229f080085953611ffb708a0df5b7f37a253ec" failed: exit status 1
```

I don’t know where to use the gcloud app deploy -image url.

Help me how to gcloud app deploy image url in Container Registry using git and build triggers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a `cloudbuild.yaml` file with something like this:

```
steps:
# Build the Docker image.
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app', '.']
# Push it to GCR.
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app']
# Deploy your Flex app from the image in GCR.
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['app', 'deploy', 'app.yaml', '--image-url=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app']
# Note that this build pushes this image.
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app']
```

Add this file to your repository and configure a build trigger that executes that when you push to your branch.

Comment: Thanks, Jason Hall, I tried cloudbuild.yaml as per your reply. But I got this error "Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/project-id]. Please make sure you are using the correct project ID and that you have permission to view applications on the project." I enabled billing of the project, and GAE ADMIN API also enabled.I m using correct project ID.May I know what missing?

Comment: Oh right I forgot to mention you need to grant app deploy permissions to your project's builder service account, named like PROJECT-NUM@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: @Sattanathan Documentation on granting app deploy permissions can be found at https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/how-to/service-account-permissions#granting_additional_access

Comment: Thank Jason hall & David Bendory - Auto deployment from git - container registry to GAE FE success. But Opening URL I got 404 Not found nginx, Please see this Build Log Details (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DIxlca_YPNvbrWrvo1TIzT2qYNslkEmDweVr9R3UA_0/edit#gid=0). Why I m getting 404 ?

Comment: Hi, Please any one help me, Why I got 404 not found after successful auto deployment?

Comment: Hi Sattanathan, I'm not sure why your deployment would result in a 404. If you build and deploy the image locally does the app deploy correctly? You might have better luck asking a new question tagged with [google-app-engine] to get more help with your 404 problem.

Comment: Thanks, jason Hall, I 'll try if not will open new question